# How to fill a wpf tree view using mvvm from a model with "infinte" levels

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, treeview

I have that entity framework model that self inner where a user can make sub categories to sub categories for as many as necessary.

```cs
public class Category
{
    public Category()
    {
        SubCategories = new ObservableCollection<Category>();
    }

    [Column("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Column("ParentID")]
    public int? ParentID { get; set; }


    [ForeignKey("ParentID")]
    public virtual ObservableCollection<Category> SubCategories { get; set; }
}
```

I was thinking of populating a tree view with it using foreach like this:

```cs
Categories = new ObservableCollection<Category>(db.Categories.Where(x => x.ParentID == null));

foreach (var item in Categories)
{
    SubCategoriesModel = new ObservableCollection<Category>(db.Categories.Where(x => x.ParentID == item.Id));
    foreach (var subitem in SubCategoriesModel)
    {
        item.SubCategories.Add(subitem);
    }
}
```

```xaml
<TreeView Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}" MinWidth="220">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type data:Categories}" ItemsSource="{Binding SubCategories}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" Margin="3 2" />
                <TextBlock Text=" - "/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="3 2" />
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
    <e:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <behaviours:BindableSelectedItemBehavior SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTreeCategory, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </e:Interaction.Behaviors>
</TreeView>
```

I realized that this not going to work. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: @dymanoid sorry about that, that was a typo and it get the data but only one level of it unless i want to repeat the foreach statement forever

Comment: The only option I see is to load it when the item gets expanded and not before that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method 1**

When you are dealing with a potentially infinite number of sub-levels (for example because items can reference each other and would cause an infinite loop during recursion), I'd recommend populating the items when they are first expanded.

**Method 2**

If you don't have recursions and want to load all data at once, you can simply do so by loading it in a recursive method (be careful though - if the levels go too deep you might get a StackOverflowException)

---

## Example Method 1

A very simple viewmodel for this situation could look like this:

```cs
public class Node
{
    public uint NodeId { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public bool ChildrenLoaded { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<Node> Children { get; set; }

    public Node()
    {
        ChildrenLoaded = false;
        Children = new ObservableCollection<Node>();
    }

    public void LoadChildNodes()
    {
        if (ChildrenLoaded) return;

        // e.g. Every SubCategory with a parentId of this NodeId
        var newChildren = whereverYourDataComesFrom.LoadChildNodes(NodeId);

        Children.Clear();
        foreach (Node child in newChildren)
            Children.Add(child);

        ChildrenLoaded = true;
    }
}
```

Set the Treeview up like this, where `Nodes` is one or more root nodes that you load first. (`Categories` with ParentId = null in your example)

```xaml
<TreeView TreeViewItem.Expanded="TreeViewItem_Expanded" ItemsSource="{Binding Nodes}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

The [`TreeViewItem.Expanded`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.treeviewitem.expanded?view=netframework-4.8) event is a so called [RoutedEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/routed-events-overview) btw. It's not fired by the TreeView, but the TreeViewItems themselves and just *bubbles* up your visual tree (that's the actual technical term for it, there is also *tunneling* and *direct*).

Whenever a node is expanded for the first time you simply load all the child nodes in the `TreeViewItem_Expanded` event handler.

```cs
private void TreeViewItem_Expanded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Node node = ((FrameworkElement)e.OriginalSource).DataContext as Node;
    if (node == null) return;

    node.LoadChildNodes();
}
```

So no matter how many items you have and if the reference each other, you only load the root nodes and everything else happens on-demand.

Translating that principle to your specific example, I'd simply split the load method of your data into your root `Category` entries and load the `SubCategories` in the Expanded event handler instead of pre-loading everything.

Since most of your code is already almost identical, I think this should be a rather easy modification.

---

## Example Method 2

```
private void LoadRootCategories()
{
    Categories = new ObservableCollection<Category>(db.Categories.Where(x => x.ParentID == null));

    foreach (var item in Categories)
    {
        LoadSubCategories(item)
    }
}

private void LoadSubCategories(Category item)
{
    item.SubCategories = new ObservableCollection<Category>(db.Categories.Where(x => x.ParentID == item.Id));
    
    foreach (var subitem in item.SubCategories)
    {
        // Recursive call
        LoadSubCategories(subitem);
    }
}
```